# Replace text in a bash script that is not a variable

Tags: bash, terminal

So I recently made a simple bash script which I want to share with other people. So I tried making the script search for files in a folder in which other people will place them, which worked fine for a few files.

Though I have a command in my script that doesn't accept the variables, they get passed, but they don't get replaced in the command. So instead of using a variable I had to use the path to the files, which are only on my computer.

And since I want everyone to use that script I need a way to replace these paths. So I thought of this:

Use the same command that found the other file to find this one. Then replace the path to the file in the script with the path that was found by the command.

Though my problem is, that I haven't found something that is what I wanted. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#variables that store the paths

dtree=$(find Downgrade -type f -iname DeviceTree*) 
ramdisk=$(find Downgrade -type f -iname *.dmg)
kernel=$(find Downgrade -type f -iname kernelcache*)

#the execution of the command. (Using normal EOF without ”” doesn’t replace the strings.)

./irecovery -s <<"EOF" >/dev/null

/send Downgrade/DeviceTree.n90ap.img3 #This needs to be replaced by $dtree
devicetree
/send Downgrade/048-2441-007.dmg #This needs to be replaced by $ramdisk
ramdisk
/send Downgrade/kernelcache.release.n90 #This needs to be replaced by $kernel
bootx
/exit
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure about your question, you can try replacing string using `sed`

`sed "s/old/new/g"`